# CLISP recursive powers of cubes function that returns a list

Tags: function, recursion, lisp, common-lisp, exponent

I'm looking for help in writing a function that returns a list of the first 15 cubes. Here's what I have so far, and I'm getting a stack overflow:

```
(defun cubes (dec lst) ;takes a number and a list as params
   (if (= dec 0) lst ;if dec is 0 return the list
       (cons (threes (- dec 1) lst))) ;;else decrement and call it again
)
```

I am calling it with the following code:

```
(cubes 15 nil) ;should print first 15 cubes
```

I just started on LISP today. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't you want to calculate cubes somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, your function has a slight issue with it: :-)

1. You're recursing into `threes` instead of `cubes`.
2. You're trying to call `cons` with one argument (it requires two).
3. You're not changing the value of `lst` in the recursion, so, since the base case returns `lst`, you'll always get the initial `lst` value you passed in.

Here's a fixed version:

```
(defun cubes (dec lst)
  (if (zerop dec)
      lst
      (cubes (1- dec) (cons (* dec dec dec) lst))))
```

Comment: Don't you want to calculate cubes somewhere?

Comment: @Svante Oops. Was too focused on getting the code working and neglected to look at the problem domain.

Comment: @DomnWerner `(* dec dec dec)` is the same as `dec * dec * dec` in infix. It basically evaluates to the cube of `dec`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of the loop facility, and you SHOULD check if the initial value of dec is positive, otherwise you may end up with infinite loop/recursion:

```
(defun cubes (dec lst)
       (append
          (when (plusp dec)
                (loop for i from 1 to dec collect (expt i 3)))
          lst))
```

Comment: You don't need `lst`, `append`, `when`.

Comment: I mean: `(defun cubes (n) (when (plusp n) (loop :for i :from 1 :to n :collect (expt i 3))))`.

Comment: That's right, but the author's function took an integer and a list, so suggested variants should as well.

Comment: `(defun cubes (n list) (declare (ignore list)) (when (plusp n) (loop :for i :from 1 :to n :collect (expt i 3))))`

Comment: The author's variant conses cubes to the list given as the second parameter, while yours just ignores it. When I wrote my variant, I took into account what the original variant actually did.

Comment: Chill out, guys. They both helped me learn a ton! Job well done, guys.